# how to move the cursor to the middle of the line in evil of emacs?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

The following link gives an answer in vim,

https://superuser.com/questions/216411/go-to-middle-of-line-in-vim

using the following script

```
map gm :call cursor(0, virtcol('$')/2)<CR>
```

but how to do that in emacs? put it inside .emacs? and how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function will put the cursor on the middle point of the line.  The following line binds it to `gm` (which clobbers the default `evil-middle-of-visual-line`, by the way):

```
(defun middle-of-line ()
  "Put cursor at the middle point of the line."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (/ (+ (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)) 2)))

(define-key evil-motion-state-map "gm" 'middle-of-line)
```

Put those lines in your `.emacs` file; the `define-key` line should come after the part that initializes `evil`.  (FYI: the normal state map inherits from the motion state map.)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
(defun middle-of-line ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((eol-pos (progn
                    (end-of-line)
                    (point)))
       (bol-pos (progn
                    (beginning-of-line)
                    (point))))
     (forward-char (/ (- eol-pos bol-pos) 2))))
```

Comment: then I added the following "(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "gm") 'middle-of-line) " in the .emacs, but gm doesn't work in evil, how to bind that function to gm in vim normal mode?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use evil - perhaps someone else can help you here (Another Question? - How to add keybindings to evil-mode) or, maybe something in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil can help?

Comment: Seems you need to add to the desired 'mode' within evil - this document provides some information on this, https://gitorious.org/evil/evil/blobs/raw/doc/doc/evil.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I use this version:

```
(defun aborn/move-middle-of-line (arg)
  "Smart move point to the middle of current displayed line." 
  (interactive "P")
  (if (or (bolp) (eolp))
      (goto-char (/ (+ (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)) 2))
    (progn
      (goto-char (/ (+ (point)
                       (if arg (point-at-eol) (point-at-bol)))
                    2)))))
```